# Get from hls.js response code and message from playlist.m3u8

Tags: javascript, http, response, m3u8, hls.js

The objective here is to get the HTTP response code and message from my source. I try to load an HTTP 401 (to test) with custom message playlist.m3u8 and I need to get the 401 code and message in my javascript. In browser console i can see both 401 and custom message in response tab. How can i do this?

I tried to see this documentation: https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/blob/master/docs/API.md#third-step-load-a-manifest

Under NETWORK ISSUE but the manifestLoadError data.response show me '0' as response code and '' as response text

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, i added CORS header to my server code and everything works fine, yeah